# Different type of ellipse in PCA analysis

Tags: r, pca

What are the differences between ellipses computed when working with individual factor map in R with `coord.ellipse` (from `FactoMineR` package) and `ordiellipse` (from `vegan` package) ?

Below some reproducible code :

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(vegan)
data(decathlon)

res.pca = PCA(decathlon[,1:10], scale.unit=TRUE, ncp=5, graph=T) 
pcarda <- rda(decathlon[,1:10],scale=T)
```

With FactomMineR from [example here](http://factominer.free.fr/classical-methods/principal-components-analysis.html).

```
concat = cbind.data.frame(decathlon[,13],res.pca$ind$coord)
ellipse.coord = coord.ellipse(concat,bary=T)
plot.PCA(res.pca,ellipse=ellipse.coord,cex=0.8)
```

With ordiellipse :

```
ordiplot(pcarda)
ordiellipse(pcarda,groups = decathlon[,13])
```

Those ellipses provide a completely different result...

I want to visually evaluate if the variables can actually discriminate my groups. With coord.ellipse , ellipses are almost separated (hypothesis accepted) and with `ordiellipse` they are mostly overlapping (hypothesis rejected).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`coord.ellipse`constructs confidence ellipses for the barycenters of the categorical variables (by default with a threshold 0.95, see its help).

`ordiellipse` constructs standard deviation ellipses for the points or their weighted averages (see the help for the parameter `kind`).

They are equivalent if you give them the same parameters (they are different by default). For example:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
ellipse.coord = coord.ellipse(concat,bary=TRUE,conf=0.95)
plot.PCA(res.pca,ellipse=ellipse.coord,cex=0.8,ylim=c(-4,4),xlim=c(-4,4))
ordiplot(pcarda,ylim=c(-2,2),xlim=c(-2,2))
ordiellipse(pcarda,groups = decathlon[,13],conf=0.95,kind="se")
```

To get :

[image]

It doesn't look exactly the same because the scale for the graphics are slightly different (and difficult to adjust) but you can see that they separate the points exactly the same way.

Then how to test your hypothesis is a question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Briefly, if you want to represent that your groups are disjoint just plot the individuals with two different colors : they are not. 
If you want to represent the difference between the barycenters (kind of the means) of your groups then go with the 95% ellipse (the one I displayed here). It is not very conclusive either from my point of view but you see... or you test but for that you should really ask an other question and probably more on Cross Validated than here.

Comment: All right, but what are the differences between the two ? In my case, I want to evaluate if my groups are well discriminated with the variables ... The two method in this specific case provide different result. One with almost separated ellipses and the other with mostly overlapping ellipses

Comment: Well, the difference is the same than between a 95% credible interval and a standard deviation. At some point you have to dive into the help of these functions ...

Comment: Thanks for your help !